# Getting different values of date in mysql workbench and java app

Tags: java, mysql

The hour value that i get using select function on a table in mysql workbench is different than the one that i get using a connection in java. Java returns always 1h ahead.

```
**Table1**
id INT
data DATETIME
```

The code i'm using to access the database from the java program is this:

```
public void iniConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    c = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,password);   
}

public void closeConnection() throws SQLException{
            c.close();           
    }

public ArrayList execGetProcedure(String procedimento) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    iniConnection();
        Statement st = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(procedimento);
        ArrayList<Object> out = new ArrayList<Object>();
        int i = 1;
        int colC = res.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while(res.next()){
            while(i<(colC+1)){
                out.add(res.getObject(i));
                i++;
            }          
            i=1;              
        }
        st.close();
        res.close();
        closeConnection();
    return out;
}
```

this function execGetProcedure returns an arraylist which i use after to fill a table.

the thing is, if in the database the data (datetime) value is 2018-10-11 18:50:40 what i get in the arraylist is 2018-10-11 19:50:40.
Hope you can help.

Ps: this is the content of a config file i use to get the login, password and database location/name.

```
 jdbc:mysql://192.168.96.7:3306/Src?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT
 perf
 cor
```

Comment: Timezone issue?

Comment: dont think so, the server timezone is the same im using in the config file GMT, greenwich. the thing is, when i use select data from Table1 i get a value different than the one that's there.Heard that maybe the problem was that when exporting the value mysql uses something like new TimeStamp() with some parameters in it and returns that. But i think thats not the case because the insertion method uses now() function (mysql function) - the server date, so if he writes it well it should deliver it well.:P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question fails to specify what JDBC driver is in use, and fails to note exactly the data type of the column. So I cannot be specific, but here is some general help.

## Dynamically-applied time zone is confusing

Many tools and database drivers dynamically apply a default time zone while retrieving a date-time value. While well-intentioned, this only creates confusion and ambiguity.

Such behavior is an anti-feature in my opinion. For one thing, it obfuscates the actual data stored in the database. For another, programmers and sysadmins should generally be working in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) for logging, debugging, tracing, reporting, and data storage/exchange.

## JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2, the modern approach to retrieving date-time values from your database is to use the *java.time* classes.

## *java.time*

For a date-only type, akin to SQL-standard `DATE`, use `LocalDate` class. The `LocalDate` class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

For a moment type, akin to SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use `OffsetDateTime`. The `OffsetDateTime` class represents a date with time-of-day and an offset-from-UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

For a date with time-of-day but lacking time zone or offset-from-UTC, akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use `LocalDateTime`. Note that this type does *not* represent a moment, only *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours (the range of time zones around the globe).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: tha JDBC driver im using is mysql-connector-java-8.0.11. and the column data type is DATETIME.